# how to get the path of the image(.png) file that is stored in assets folder in android

Tags: android, path, absolute-path, android-assets

I have few images in assets folder i want to retrieve the path of the each image file and copy them into array and finally set to image view with some condition. i have used the below code.But it did not workout for me. may i know where i am going wrong.

```
final Uri ASSETS_URI = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset");
final String[] IMAGE_IDS =new String[] {ASSETS_URI+"/"+"one.png",ASSETS_URI+"/"+"two.png",ASSETS_URI+"/"+"three.png"};

iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
if(i>=0 & i< IMAGE_IDS.length-1)
   i=i+1;
else if(i==IMAGE_IDS.length-1)
   i=0;

iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(IMAGE_IDS[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change :

```
    final Uri ASSETS_URI = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset");
```

to this:

```
   final String ASSETS_URI = "file:///android_asset";
```

I think the problem is that you are concatenating and Uri with a String. If you declare ASSETS_URI as String then everything is String and later parsed to Uri.

Comment: i changed it to string but i am still getting the same error like: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: file:///android_asset/one.png